# Tkinter Wait for Key to Be Pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, wait

I am using Python 3 and Tkinter, and I have a `wait()` function, waiting until the right arrow key or left arrow key is pressed, however, it just freezes everything, and I have to force stop the program.

```
from tkinter import *

right = left = False

def setLeft(event):
    global left
    left = True
    print('Left!')
def setRight(event):
    global right
    right = True
    print('Right!')

def wait():
    global right, left
    left = right = 0
    while not (left or right):
        pass
    print(right) #0 for left, 1 for right
    left = right = 0


root = Tk()
root.bind('<Left>', setLeft)
root.bind('<Right>', setRight)
```

Is there a way for the `wait()` function to work like it is supposed to, or do I need to find a different way?

Comment: Why do you need to wait? A GUI is constantly in a waiting state by default. Just put code you want to run in `setLeft` and `setRight`

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to wait for either key to be pressed, then find out which one it was, so that I can setup a tree of sorts.

Comment: But you know which one was clicked: if `setLeft` is called, the left arrow was pressed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to navigate through a tree, which would be much harder if I had to store the state instead of just having a bunch of nested ifs and elses.

Comment: what kind of tree? Is it a tree-like widget? A document (ie: xml)? I don't understand why you think you need to add an additional wait on top of the waiting that the GUI is already doing. Please show a slightly larger example that shows how you plan to actually use this wait function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a different way, because of event-driven nature of Tkinter GUI programming. When some event lead you to your `wait()` function there it is: you're stuck in infinite loop, and you can't get outside with events anymore!

As @Bryan Oakley [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126361/tkinter-wait-for-key-to-be-pressed#comment71421570_42126361) - GUI is constantly in a waiting state by default, since you reached a `mainloop()`. And I think, that you trying just suppress all other events (or just navigate keys) when user navigating through a tree , except this two (Left and Right clicks).

So here is a small example:

```
import tkinter as tk


# Main - application
class App(tk.Tk):
    # init of our application
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(width=450, height=100)
        self.wm_title('Just another example from SO')
        self.wait_state = False
        self.init_events()

    # switch state
    def switch_wait_state(self, event):
        self.wait_state = not self.wait_state
        print('Wait state switched to: %s ' % self.wait_state)

    # init events
    def init_events(self):
        self.bind('<Key>', self.wait)
        self.bind('<Control-s>', self.switch_wait_state)

    # waiter(listener) for keypress
    def wait(self, event):
        if self.wait_state and any(key == event.keysym for key in ['Left', 'Right']):
            print('I have successfully waited until %s keypress!' % event.keysym)
            self.do_smth(event.keysym)
        else:
            print('Wait state: %s , KeyPress: %s' % (self.wait_state, event.keysym))
            self.do_nhth()

    @staticmethod
    def do_smth(side):
        print("Don't be rude with me, Im trying my best on a %s side!" % side)

    @staticmethod
    def do_nhth():
        pass


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```